# Peut-on, contre son avis, reposter un court commentaire d'un autre utilisateur en tant que réponse à sa propre question ?

Tags: discussion, moderation, answer-quality, comments

Dans [deux](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53546/diff%C3%A9rence-entre-hypercentre-et-centre-ville-etc) de ses [questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53558/des-personnes-qui-sont-se-mettent-en-sur-la-ligne-implique-t-il-obligatoire) récentes, @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t a isolé des commentaires d'autres personnes et les a reposté comme réponses alors même que leurs auteurs contestaient qu'il s'agissait de réponses.

La question de "commentaire vs réponse" est un poncif qui semble toujours avoir divisé les communautés stackoverflow. Je n'ai pas trouvé de règle inter-communautés claire à ce sujet, mais voici ce qui en est dit dans la réponse acceptée à [un des topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments) (plutôt ancien) ayant fait le plus de votes sur la question sur meta.stackexchange :

> Most often I do this when I have some input to give that I think is helpful, but I don't have the time/care to write a detailed answer that meets my personal quality standards. Rather than an incomplete answer or not helping at all, I'll leave a comment to point them in the right direction.

Ou [encore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163587/when-to-answer-vs-when-to-just-comment) :

> Normally, something that answers the question should be written as answer. Sometimes, users write an answer as comment for different reasons:
>
> - They don't have the time to write a more complete answer, and they write the comment as a hint for somebody else who could be able to write a more complete answer
> - They are not sure about the answer, which could be just a guess
> - The question is not that clear, and they write an answer as comment, hoping the OP comments about that, making more clear what the expected answer is
> - They are going to vote to close the question

Je partage l'irritation que peuvent ressentir certains à toujours se voir adjoindre des commentaires mais pas ou très peu de réponses (*).
Je peux même admettre que certains commentaires sont des réflexes de déni facile face à une question dont on n'a pas la clé. Mais je me demande si la réaction est la bonne à partir du moment où cela se fait sans le consentement des auteurs des commentaires qui se sont d'ailleurs **opposés à les considérer comme réponses**.

A tout le moins, je m'attendrais à ce que ce soit un modérateur qui promeuve le commentaire en réponse s'il est jugé acceptable comme solution pour la communauté, mais pas que l'auteur de la question d'origine le fasse. Surtout si c'est pour finir par ne pas upvoter ni valider la "réponse-commentaire" qu'on a promue.

PS : je ne cherche pas à résoudre ce cas particulier, ce qui est fait est fait, mais à dégager une règle plus globale dans l'esprit de faciliter le vivre ensemble de la communauté.

*( * ) Avis personnel : cela vient de questions très pointues et pertinentes pour lesquelles on manque d'experts professionnels de la langue intervenant sur french.stackexchange.com, contrairement à d'autres sous-sites qui en regorgent.*

Comment: [Allow asker to upgrade comment to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117374/340816).

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas d'autre juge sur la pertinence d'une question ou d'une réponse que les votes. Un modérateur comme tout autre membre peut choisir de promouvoir un commentaire en tant que réponse. C'est un droit garanti par la licence *creative commons* que tous ceux qui publient quelque chose sur StackExchange ont accepté.

Si un membre souhaite avoir l'avis de la communauté sur le commentaire d'un autre membre et lui donne pour cela plus de visibilité, je ne vois pas ce qui pourrait gêner ce dernier. Après tout, tout commentaire est bien écrit pour être lu.

S'il n'a pas été écrit en tant que réponse par peur d'être *downvoté*, la publication tierce élimine le risque de perte de points de réputation.

Il ne s'agit pas d'un plagiat puisque l'auteur est mentionné et un lien vers la source est fourni.

Il ne s'agit pas d'une tentative d'appropriation de la réputation que pourrait apporter la réponse puisqu'il s'agit d'un *community wiki*, hors du cadre du système de réputation.

Si la personne qui a posté le commentaire change d'avis et décide de proposer une réponse, c'est aussi parfaitement son droit.

Si elle n'est pas satisfaite de la manière dont son commentaire a été repris, elle peut modifier la réponse, plus encore ici puisqu'il s'agit d'un *community wiki*. C'est d'ailleurs un avantage certain par rapport aux commentaires qui ne sont plus modifiables après un délai assez court. L'auteur d'un commentaire peut toujours l'effacer et le réécrire plus loin, mais on perd la chronologie et parfois la logique de la discussion si ce commentaire à fait l'objet d'autres commentaires. Si on souhaitait entamer une discussion sur la question, ce qui arrive souvent et j'avoue y participer souvent, il vaudrait mieux passer par le *chat*. Je trouve d'ailleurs dommage qu'il n'y ait pas de bouton qui permette de démarrer un chat associé à une question et qu'il faille attendre que Stack-Exchange éventuellement nous le propose pour pouvoir le faire.

Il n'y a donc pour moi rien qui aille à l'encontre du *vivre ensemble* dans ces promotions de commentaires.

La licence sous laquelle sont publiées les contributions interdit de toute façon de limiter le droit de republication. Il ne peut donc être question de remettre en cause ce droit sur FSE, ce qui serait une violation de [CC-by-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) dont voici les termes :

> ***You are free to:***
> ***Share** — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format*
> ***Adapt** — remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose, even commercially.*
> *This license is acceptable for Free Cultural Works.*
> *The licensor cannot revoke these freedoms as long as you follow the license terms.*
>
> ***Under the following terms**:*
> ***Attribution** — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.*
> ***ShareAlike** — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.*

Comment: Dont acte sur l'aspect légal, merci. Je ne mets pas la réponse en validé pour l'instant parce qu'elle néglige plusieurs points de la Q sur l'aspect bienséance/consentement. Ma question portait sur des commentaires expressément qualifiés de non-réponses par leurs auteurs et qui ont quand même été convertis en réponses dans un esprit qu'on peut qualifier de passif-agressif, orienté pour servir une opinion particulière dans la "guerre de chapelles" commentaires vs réponses, de manière cynique puisque la réponse CW ainsi créée n'est même pas considérée comme bonne par l'OP.

Comment: J'ai répondu au deuxième point. Il ne s'agit pas de cynisme mais d' *avoir l'avis de la communauté sur le commentaire d'un autre membre*. Un commentaire promu pourrait aussi bien avoir des votes négatifs. Avec l'impossibilité de modifier, un gros défaut des commentaires est aussi de ne pouvoir que les upvoter mais pas les downvoter. On peut seulement signaler à un modérateur un commentaire pour un problème sérieux, mais c'est inadapté dans ce cas. Pour ce qui est d'attitude passive-aggressive, c'est très subjectif. Je ne peux que t'encourager à désescalader le sujet et à tourner la page.

Comment: @jiliagre "Je n'ai que faire de ...", "opinions décousues et inconséquentes", (entre autres commentaires similaires supprimés) sont des commentaires objectivement agressifs.

Comment: Je désescalade autant que je peux en prenant moult pincettes dans mes propos, faisant amende honorable etc., mais la désescalade ne peut pas être à sens unique.

Comment: Wow... je reste sans voix face à tant d'animosité :( Pour info, je ne m'inclus pas dans les professionnels de la langue et c'est juste un constat qui me concerne aussi moi. Pas une critique de la qualité des réponses des autres puisque je cite justement des cas où il n'y a pas de réponses, que des commentaires.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de provocation dans ma question mais une volonté de compréhension et de conciliation. Tu me prêtes des propos que je n'ai pas tenus sur les enfantillages et le crêpage de chignon. Libre à toi de flagger un commentaire mais je ne vois pas lequel.

Comment: Ouch, je t'ai effectivement confondu avec un autre. Désolé, je retire ce commentaire.

Comment: Pour ce qui est des professionnels de la langue, ça ne veut pas dire grand chose. Il y a de vrais experts qui participent à FSE et produisent des réponses brillantes, mais il y a aussi des "professionnels" (au moins une) qui comptent parmi les pires contributeurs du site...

Comment: Ce que je veux dire, c'est qu'il nous faudrait un prof de littérature spécialiste du XIXè quand une question demande d'interpréter un poème de Verlaine, une.e linguiste quand il y a débat sur l'évolution historique de la fonction d'un mot dans une expression,etc. Ces experts ne sont dans l'immense majorité des cas pas sur FLSE. Ces questions sont pourtant nombreuses et passionnantes et ça me chagrine autant que les auteurs quand elles ne reçoivent aucune réponse. Mais il ne faut pas mettre la faute sur les "simples commentateurs" qui font de leur mieux pour ne pas laisser une question en plan.

Comment: C'est trop ambitieux et trop élitiste. Les profs de littérature du XIXe siècle ne courent effectivement pas les sites comme FSE, mais il leur arrive de publier leur savoir et rien n'empêche à des amateurs comme beaucoup ici de piocher la dedans et de tenter de répondre de leur mieux. Les réponses ne sont de toute façon pas figées dans le marbre. Tout le monde peut corriger, ajuster une réponse pour l'améliorer. Il y a aussi beaucoup de questions d'apprenants FLE et pour ces dernières, tout locuteur natif est un expert potentiel avec des dizaines d'années de pratique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148090/discussion-between-guillaume31-and-jlliagre).